# How to combine several features on

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, decorator

From time to time I am facing the same problem when I want to design a component whose implementations can provide any subsets of features.

Here is an example for a simple message queue system:

- All implementations MUST be able to *push* and *poll* a simple message string at least
- Implementations CAN also accept message scheduling
- Implementations CAN also accept to name messages (named pipes, channels or whatever)

With theses requirements, my model could be the following:

```php
interface QueueInterface
{
    function push($message);
    function poll();
}

// If a message is simply "pushed" then the $scheduleTime is now
interface ScheduledQueueInterface /* extends QueueInterface */
{
    function schedule($message, DateTime $scheduleTime);
}

// If a message is simply "pushed" then the channel is NULL
interface NamedQueueInterface /* extends QueueInterface */
{
    function pushInChannel($message, $channel);
    function pollFromChannel($channel);
}
```

Now, as my vanilla QueueInterface is content agnostic, I should be able to code a decorator to emulate named channels by embedding the channel name in the message string:

```php
 // Channel are concatenated on the front of the message and separated by a NULL char
class NamedQueueDecorator implements NamedQueueInterface, QueueInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @var QueueInterface
     */
    protected $queue;

    function pushInChannel($message, $channel)
    {
        $this->queue->push("$channel\0$message");
    }

    function pollFromChannel($channel)
    {
        // ???
    }

    function push($message)
    {
        $this->queue->push("\0$message");
    }

    function poll()
    {
        return substr($message = $this->queue->poll(), strpos($message, "\0") + 1);
    }
}
```

(my example is not so great because I don't know how to `pollFromChannel()` with my decorator but imagine this is possible and straightforward)

Now, my question is: what if the inner queue in my decorator implements `ScheduledQueueInterface`?
Should I create one decorator which implements only `QueueInterface` and another one which implements also `ScheduledQueueInterface`?
Should I create only one decorator which implements implements whatever "features" exists? And if I do so, what about an inner queue which does not implement a feature? (`$this->queue->schedule($message, $scheduledTime)` would fail for example)

The same problem is met also with Http clients implementing the same set of feature interfaces: they can implement many features (authentication, cache control, redirect, ...) but if one Http client but we want to be able to implement a feature aside and decorate a Http client lacking this feature to enrich it.

So do you know a way to propose a set of features and partial implementations and "feature patches" while being respectful to interfaces?